# How to print a large list of URLs to PDF?

Tags: pdf, printing, automation

I have a bunch of URLs (1000s) in a spreadsheet.  They point at an internal web application.  I need to load each one as rendered by a browser, print it to PDF, and then assemble all of the PDFs into one large document.

Right now we have humans doing this horrible work.  My hope is to automate somehow.  The best quick-and-dirty solution I've come up with so far is to create a Selenium script.  Is there a quicker-and-dirtier way?

Answer (score 3):

First, save the column with the urls in your spreadsheet as CSV (urls.csv) so you have only one url per line, no commas at the beginning or end.
Then, assuming you are on a Windows machine, you could download and use http://cutycapt.sourceforge.net/ from the command line with a batch file:

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET /A COUNT=1
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%i IN (urls.csv) DO (
    CutyCapt --url=%%i --min-width=1024 --out-format=jpeg --out=screenshot!COUNT!.png
    SET /A COUNT+=1
)
```

CutyCapt must be in the same dir as the BAT and CSV files. It will output the Websites as JPEG screenhots. If you have Acrobat Pro installed, you can right-click those and merge them into one PDF. That should save you some money ;)

Comment: This saved me hours of work.  Tnx! . However, I used wkHtmlToPdf instead of CutyCapt which is much better in my opinion: https://wkhtmltopdf.org/usage/wkhtmltopdf.txt

Answer (score 3):

First write all your URL's in a .htm file on your computer.

in Acrobat Pro (v9) :

1. Menu file > Create PDF > From Web Page… => Opens the 'Create PDF' window
2. Enter the URL = http/... or in your case browse to the html file you created
3. Click 'Capture Multiple Levels' > Get only = 2 levels
4. Click 'Settings…" to adjust the page size, margins, etc
5. Click 'Create' and wait while Acrobat constructs the file

Comment: One benefit of this approach is your resulting PDF's will have high fidelity, and embedded images.

Comment: Works well, remember to put your links in hyperlink format for Acrobat can read them: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_links.asp